# ExpressionEngine channel form file upload

Tags: forms, file, upload, expressionengine

I'm trying to allow my users to upload a videos. My channel has "file" as the first channel field.

Made a channel form with the following code. When I try to upload anything I get the error field_id_5 is a required field (this is my file field). The only way i get the form to go through is if I make the video file not require, in which case all the other info goes through.

WHen i create a post in this channel through the EE control panel, it works. Video file is uploaded and all and it shows up in my channel in the video player.

Any help? Very new to coding so it may be a very simple mistake somewhere.. apologies :)

I managed to get it working with {field:video_file} instead of input tags but then I can't control what types of files they can send...

```
{exp:channel:form channel="video_post_uploaded"}

            <p class="form_text">Post Title:
            <br><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();" class="form_input">

            <!-- <p>URL Title: -->
            <br><input type="hidden" id="url_title" name="url_title" value="{url_title}" class="form_input">
            <!-- <p class="instructions">Don't worry about this one, it fills itself out automatically. -->

            <p>Upload Video:
            <p><input type="file" name="video_file">
            <p class="instructions">{instructions:video_file}

            <p>Game:
            <br><select name="game_title_uploaded">
                {options:game_title_uploaded}
                    <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
                {/options:game_title_uploaded}
                </select>
            <p class="instructions">{instructions:game_title_uploaded}

        {status_menu}
        <select name="status" class="hidden">
        {select_options}
        </select>
        {/status_menu}

            <p><input type="submit" value="Post It!" class="submit_button">
            {/exp:channel:form}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use it with just input type file. EE needs another hidden field to indicate directory of file to upload.

You can use it like this:

```
<input type="file" name="video_file">
<input type="hidden" name="video_file_directory" value="1">
```